# Two feature branches. Where to put modifcations?

Tags: git, git-flow, feature-branch

I'm using typical git branche `flow`. The main branch is `develop` and  feature branches are created when needed. Let's say, that I created `feature-test` branch. Next I created and tested one Class `Test`. Finally the branch was merged into `develop`. Now I'm working on the second branch and noticed that `Test` class should have one more method that would be used inside files on the current branch.

What should I do in this case? Make modifications on the current branch or on the previous?

Comment: there no unique answer to this question, it is really opinion-based. But most of all, _it depends_ on your company guidelines, if they exist

Answer (score 0):

As you have already merged `feature-test` branch into `develop` branch, I would suggest you to create new feature branch `feature-testupdate` forked out of develop branch, as it seems the policy your company has been following.

Handle one thing at a time. Forget about your previous `feature-test` branch and start a fresh feature branch `feature-test-updated` out of `develop`. Now work on your modifications on the fresh feature branch `feature-test-updated`.